# STRING_AGG with Union All

Tags: sql, t-sql

I want to do STRING_AGG with union all. here are my tables.

```
        SELECT
            C1 = P1
        FROM
            elt.Api


        UNION ALL 

        SELECT
            C1 = E1
        FROM
            elt.Api2
```

for one table STRING_AGG is working fine.

```
SELECT STRING_AGG(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(max), ISNULL(P1,'N/A')), ',') AS C1 FROM
    elt.Api
```

how should I do same with UNION ALL? Do I have to write the cursor for this ?

Comment: Select from your query as a derived table `SELECT STRING_AGG(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(max), ISNULL(C1,'N/A')), ',') AS C1 FROM ( _your query_ ) t` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Something like this

```
SELECT STRING_AGG(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(max), ISNULL(c1,'N/A')), ',') AS C1
FROM
(SELECT
        C1 = P1
    FROM
        elt.Api


    UNION ALL 

    SELECT
        C1 = E1
    FROM
        elt.Api2
) A
```